# how to use javascript variable for complete series data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i am generating a Highchart, Instead of assigning each series separately i am assigning all the series data to the variable and assigning this variable to the series section but it is not working.
Here is my code for chart

```
var seriesdata='{name: '2019',data:[3883,3961,3893,3780,4021,3765,3560,4099,3310,3403,3628,3137,]},{name: '2020',data:[3489,3883,3403,3331,2605,949,]}';
```

and my assignment of series section in chart is

```
series: [seriesdata];
```

but it is not working.
Instead of this if i am using as

```
series=[{name: '2019',data:[3883,3961,3893,3780,4021,3765,3560,4099,3310,3403,3628,3137,]},{name: '2020',data:[3489,3883,3403,3331,2605,949,]}];
```

this one  is working  perfectly.
Kindly help me to  solve the issue.

Comment: Here i  put ; by  mistake but in my code it is , only

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the data which you are trying to attach is a long string, meanwhile, Highcharts require an array of objects.

Please check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9fzod2ur/

I suggest using this data format:

```
var seriesdata = [{
    name: '2019',
    data: [3883, 3961, 3893, 3780, 4021, 3765, 3560, 4099, 3310, 3403, 3628, 3137, ]
  },
  {
    name: '2020',
    data: [3489, 3883, 3403, 3331, 2605, 949, ]
  }];
```

Comment: hi if i am giving  static value in the variable and assigning then it is working, but actually my data is coming from  database, so i  am  assigning this  data to variable in  the same format as above but it is not  working.

Comment: @MAK Could you point out how your data from database exactly look like? The online demo with a sample data will be perfect.